# Track a packet as it goes through the kernel (linux)

Tags: c, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, packet

I have two machines which are set up to use Ip-Security and machine A (lets call them A and B) has a socket which is bound to a particular UDP port on the local machine and it polls it frequently to see if anything is received on it.

When I disable Ip-security, the data between the two machines goes through fine and I send and receive the packets fine. But when Ip-Security is enabled, the packet doesn't get to that socket on machine A sent by machine B.

I do a `tcpdump` on both the machines and I can see the (encrypted) packet being sent out from machine B and being received on machine A. But after that, the packet goes to the kernel and somewhere either in the decryption of the packet or at some other phase, the packet is dropped.

I want to be able to trace the packet as it goes through the kernel and to see where it is dropped. Is there some `/proc` that I can use for this purpose? The other method I can think of is to insert debug statements all over the kernel and recompile it and then try sending the packet again and going through the debug.

Thanks and sorry for the long message but it was necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please refer to the project named [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap). It allows you to insert user-friendly scripts hooking into any kernel code, without recompiling the kernel. For example:

```
probe function("ip_rcv").call {
    printf("%d:   ->ip_rcv()\n", gettimeofday_ms()) 
}
```

It will emit a kernel print for every received packet in the network layer. Of course, you would need to read the sources to follow from there deeper into the network stack.

SystemTap is very capable and quite documented about the various hooks that can be inserted.

Comment: Oh I just looked at this today. I inserted a 100 debug statements and recompiled the kernel and found the problem. But this is awesome for future needs. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, as Dan said, SystemTap is useful.   But my favorite is ftrace.

For reference:

[Path of UDP packet in linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407452/path-of-udp-packet-in-linux-kernel/14422095#14422095)

So for tracing the network traffic in general, put the following in a bash shell and run it as root:

```
mkdir /debug
mount -t debugfs nodev /debug
mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug
echo '*' >/debug/tracing/set_ftrace_filter
echo function_graph >/debug/tracing/current_tracer
echo 1 >/debug/tracing/tracing_on
sleep 20
echo 0 >/debug/tracing/tracing_on
cat /debug/tracing/trace > /tmp/tracing.out$$
```

And so on the receiving ingress path:

```
 5)               |              tcp_recvmsg() {
 5)               |                lock_sock_nested() {
 5)   0.042 us    |                  _cond_resched();
 5)               |                  _raw_spin_lock_bh() {
 5)   0.040 us    |                    local_bh_disable();
 5)   0.414 us    |                  }
 5)   0.040 us    |                  _raw_spin_unlock();
 5)   0.040 us    |                  local_bh_enable();
 5)   1.814 us    |                }
 5)               |                skb_copy_datagram_iovec() {
 5)   0.042 us    |                  _cond_resched();
 5)   0.588 us    |                }
 5)   0.042 us    |                tcp_rcv_space_adjust();
 5)               |                __kfree_skb() {
 5)               |                  skb_release_all() {
 5)               |                    skb_release_head_state() {
 5)   0.044 us    |                      sock_rfree();
 5)   0.670 us    |                    }
 5)               |                    skb_release_data() {
 5)               |                      put_page() {
 5)   0.049 us    |                        put_compound_page();
 5)   0.449 us    |                      }
```

and this:

Netlink processing:

```
 6)               |          rtnetlink_rcv() {
 6)               |            mutex_lock() {
 6)   0.090 us    |              _cond_resched();
 6)   1.455 us    |            }
 6)               |            netlink_rcv_skb() {
 6)               |              rtnetlink_rcv_msg() {
 6)   0.150 us    |                mutex_unlock();
 6)               |                __netlink_dump_start() {
 6)               |                  netlink_lookup() {
 6)   0.091 us    |                    _raw_read_lock();
 6)   0.100 us    |                    netlink_compare();
 6)   1.791 us    |                  }
 6)               |                  mutex_lock() {
 6)   0.095 us    |                    _cond_resched();
 6)   0.913 us    |                  }
 6)   0.100 us    |                  try_module_get();
 6)   0.090 us    |                  mutex_unlock();
```

and this is the ingress also:

```
 3)               |                                                tcp_v4_rcv() {
 3)               |                                                  sk_filter() {
 3)               |                                                    security_sock_rcv_skb() {
 3)   0.076 us    |                                                      cap_socket_sock_rcv_skb();
 3)   0.867 us    |                                                    }
 3)   1.630 us    |                                                  }
 3)   0.076 us    |                                                  _raw_spin_lock();
 3)   0.477 us    |                                                  tcp_prequeue();
 3)               |                                                  tcp_v4_do_rcv() {
 3)   0.088 us    |                                                    tcp_md5_do_lookup();
 3)   0.109 us    |                                                    tcp_parse_md5sig_option();
 3)   0.072 us    |                                                    ipv4_dst_check();
 3)               |                                                    tcp_rcv_established() {
 3)   0.076 us    |                                                      tcp_parse_aligned_timestamp.part.34();
 3)               |                                                      tcp_queue_rcv() {
 3)               |                                                        tcp_try_coalesce.part.41() {
 3)   0.835 us    |                                                          skb_try_coalesce();
 3)   1.722 us    |                                                        }
 3)   2.637 us    |                                                      }
```

And this is the egress (starting from the syscall "sendmsg()"):

```
 5)               |  SyS_sendmsg() {
 5)               |    __sys_sendmsg() {
 5)               |      sockfd_lookup_light() {
 5)   0.080 us    |        fget_light();
 5)   0.502 us    |      }
 5)               |      ___sys_sendmsg() {
 5)   0.117 us    |        copy_msghdr_from_user();
 5)   0.101 us    |        verify_iovec();
 5)               |        sock_sendmsg() {
 5)               |          security_socket_sendmsg() {
 5)               |            apparmor_socket_sendmsg() {
 5)   0.092 us    |              aa_revalidate_sk();
 5)   0.580 us    |            }
 5)   1.044 us    |          }
 5)               |          unix_stream_sendmsg() {
 5)   0.113 us    |            wait_for_unix_gc();
 5)               |            security_socket_getpeersec_dgram() {
 5)   0.044 us    |              apparmor_socket_getpeersec_dgram();
 5)   0.479 us    |            }
 5)               |            sock_alloc_send_pskb() {
 5)               |              __alloc_skb() {
 5)               |                kmem_cache_alloc_node() {
 5)   0.042 us    |                  _cond_resched();
 5)   0.648 us    |                }
 5)               |                __kmalloc_reserve.isra.27() {
 5)               |                  __kmalloc_node_track_caller() {
 5)   0.074 us    |                    kmalloc_slab();
 5)   0.040 us    |                    _cond_resched();
 5)   0.504 us    |                    __slab_alloc();
 5)   1.878 us    |                  }
 5)   2.276 us    |                }
 5)   0.175 us    |                ksize();
 5)   4.217 us    |              }
```

Hope you enjoy....

Comment: Is there any reason why you using the *function_graph* tracer rather than just the *function* tracer ?

Comment: The two are different output:   see this https://lwn.net/Articles/365835/ and it shows the two different types.