# How to make a linux kernel function available to ftrace?

Tags: linux, ftrace

I want to trace 2 functions in some kernel module that are called during suspend/resume.

These functions **do appear** in "available_filter_functions".

This is how I am configuring ftrace:

```
echo nop > current_tracer
echo fun_suspend > set_ftrace_filter
echo fun_resume > set_ftrace_filter
echo function_graph > current_tracer
```

When I suspend/resume the machine, these functions are called for sure (I see logs) yet do not appear in `cat trace`

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks,

Matti

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a linux kernel function available to ftrace function\_graph tracer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271551/how-to-make-a-linux-kernel-function-available-to-ftrace-function-graph-tracer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions that i wanted to measure were in a suspend resume flow.
And apparently suspend & resume are very problematic for tracing functions(dynamic tracing), and ftrace disables the tracing during this process.
So for now you cannot trace those functions.

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that "ftrace disables the tracing during this process" means that `trace_printk()` calls that you add to the module are not added to the trace log?